# Building $MU$-spectrum via the definition of a $(B,f)$-structure

Tags: algebraic-topology, cobordism, spectra

I want to construct the them spectrum $MU$ using the definition of spectrum associated to a $(B,f)$-structure. Here are the relevant definitions:

> A $(B,f)$-structure  is a collection of strictly commutative diagrams of the form [image]
>   such that the maps $f_n$ are fibrations.
>
> A $(B,f)$-manifold is a $n$-manifold whose classifying map for the normal bundle into $BO(n)$ lifts to $X_n$.

One then pullback the canonical bundle over $BO(n)$ via $f_n$ to a bundle over $X_n$ (call it $\gamma_n$) and then define $$MX(n):=\text{Thom}(\gamma_n)$$

I want to discuss the case of complex manifold, which according to Kochman's book it's a $(B,f)$-structure. Kochman uses a different way of indexing (more general), but I want to stick as much as it is possible to these definitions (Switzer's definitions)

The problem for an almost complex structure is that one has to deal with $odd$-indexes, and my guess would be to set $X_{2n+1}=0$ since clearly (real)-odd dimensional complex manifold don't exist. The problem is that I can't retrive the commutative diagram above, since the maps $f_n$ would be the (fibration substitute) of the inclusion $BU(n)\to BO(2n)$.

So in conclusion:

> **Is it possible to build $MU$ via a $(B,f)$-structure as defined in Switzer?**

Comment: Does it fail if you let $X_{2n} = X_{2n+1} = BU(n)$?

Comment: mmh the diagram would commute, but (maybe I'm overlooking something) the homotopy groups of such spectrum should still describe the complex cobordism (and here my doubt) I would expect $0$ as homotopy groups at odd dimensional index.

But again I'm not really confident on what I said

Comment: Me neither. In any case, you might get something valuable by looking at Stong's book on cobordism.

Comment: dear @MikeMiller I checked on Stong's and it says exactly the same thing you were saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a bunch of pointed spaces $X_0, X_2, X_4, \ldots$ with maps $f_{2n} : \Sigma^2 X_{2n} \to X_{2n+2}$ you can build a spectrum out of them by setting $X_{2n+1} = \Sigma X_{2n}$, taking the maps $\Sigma X_{2n} \to X_{2n+1}$ to  be the identity and the maps $\Sigma X_{2n+1} \to X_{2n+2}$ to be $f_{2n}$.

Note that the resulting spectrum can definitely still have its odd homotopy groups be zero. The homotopy groups of a spectrum are $\pi_k(X) = \mathop{\mathrm{colim}}_{j \to \infty} \pi_{k+j}(X_j)$, which can be zero even if the individual $\pi_{k+j}(X_j)$ are not.

Comment: mmh that's a little bit odd (not claiming wrong though). I mean, suppose an odd homotopy groups is odd, using Pontrjagin-Thom theorem should I get the complex cobordism classes of **odd** dim manifolds which is non-empty. Isn't it a little bit odd? how to interpret this fact?

Comment: I'm sorry, what I wrote is pretty confusing because I called the spaces $X_{2n}$ and they are not the same $X_{2n}$'s you were talking about. I'll add some explanation when I get a bit of time, but basically my $X_{2n}$ would be the Thom space of the bundle classified by $BU(n) \to BO(2n)$. And what I said about taking $X_{2n+1} = \Sigma X_{2n}$ agrees exactly with @MikeMiller's suggestion of repeating the $BU(n)$: the Thom space of the bundle classified by the composite $BU(n) \to BO(2n) \to BO(2n+1)$ *is* the suspension of the one corresponding to $BU(n) \to BO(2n)$.

Comment: Thanks Omar! anyway I was comfused on my own (regarding my previous comment) since I believed (my bad) that I was considering *complex* manifolds and clearly there are problems with indexes